# I need to move both ellipses from X_start to X_END and back to X_START simultaneously

Tags: processing

```
final int X_START = 1 ;
final int Y_START = 250 ;
final int X_END = 500 ;
final int Y_END = 250 ; 
final int SPEED_FACTOR = 5 ;

int xCenter;
int yCenter;
int ellip1Center;
int ellip2Center;

void setup(){
  size(500,500);
}

void draw(){
  calculateDimension();
  drawSpaceship();
  moveSpaceship();
}

void calculateDimension(){
  xCenter = X_START;
  yCenter =(Y_START +Y_END)/2;
  ellip1Center = xCenter +50;
  ellip2Center = xCenter +20;
}

void drawSpaceship(){
  background(0);
  ellipse(ellip1Center, yCenter, 20, 20); 
  ellipse(ellip2Center, yCenter, 30, 30);
}

void moveSpaceship(){
  xCenter+= SPEED_FACTOR ;
}
```

I need help with the `moveSpaceship` command.
I need to move both ellipses from `X_start` to `X_END` and back to `X_START` simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the function `calculateDimension` int 2 functions. One function which initializes the reference position (`xCenter`, `yCenter`) and on function which updates the positions of the ellipses (`ellip1Center`, `ellip2Center`). Add a new variable `speed`, that holds the current speed of the ellipses, which may change to a negative speed, if the ellipse reached the end of the track.

```java
int speed;
void initDimension(){
    xCenter = X_START;
    yCenter =(Y_START +Y_END)/2;
    speed   = SPEED_FACTOR;
}

void calculateDimension(){
    ellip1Center = xCenter +50;
    ellip2Center = xCenter +20;
}
```

Call `initDimension` in `setup` and `calculateDimension` in `draw`:

```java
void setup(){
    size(500,500);
    initDimension();
}

void draw(){
    calculateDimension();
    drawSpaceship();
    moveSpaceship();
}
```

Change the direction of the ellipses by changing the variable `speed`, if the end or the start of the track is reached:

```java
void moveSpaceship(){
    xCenter += speed;
    if (xCenter >= X_END-65) speed = -SPEED_FACTOR;
    if (xCenter <= 0) speed = SPEED_FACTOR;
}
```

Comment: why does the initdimaension function have to be in the void setup()?

Comment: @TayoCruz Because it initializes all variables (`xCenter`, `yCenter`, `speed`). This variables are continuously changes in `draw`, respectively `moveSpaceship`. Calling `initDimension` in `draw` would reset all variables continuously.

Comment: @TayoCruz You're welcome. Did the answer solve your issue?